# Python 3.4 C API embedding Import errors for modules that should exist

Tags: python, c++, c, python-embedding

I am using [WinPython's](http://winpython.sourceforge.net/) python distribution as my interpreter. It should be able to import all the modules that I need in order to run some example code. I have verified this by running the module using the python.exe included with the distribution.

The problem is that when I set the PythonHome of my variable to be where the python.exe is located and also my PythonPath to the libs folder, then run the module, I am unable to import the modules necessary for the module to run.. My code is shown below..

```
#include "Python.h"
#include <cwchar>
#include <string>

int main() {

    wchar_t PythonHome[1024];
    std::wcsncpy(PythonHome, L"C:\\Users\\jchen114\\Lasagne\\WinPython\\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.1\\python-3.4.4.amd64", 1024);

    wchar_t PythonPath[1024];
    std::wcsncpy(PythonPath, L"C:\\Users\\jchen114\\Lasagne\\WinPython\\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.1\\python-3.4.4.amd64\\Lib;C:\\Users\\jchen114\\Lasagne\\WinPython\\WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.1\\python-3.4.4.amd64\\Lib\\site-packages", 1024);

    std::string ScriptPath = "C:\\users\\jchen114\\Lasagne\\mnist\\mnist.py";

    Py_SetPythonHome(PythonHome);
    Py_SetPath(PythonPath);

    Py_Initialize();

    PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pFunc = NULL;

    const char *s = Py_GetVersion();
    printf("v: %s \n", s);

    pName = PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault("importlib.machinery");
    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);


    if (pModule != NULL) {
        printf("Found module importlib.machinery \n");
        PyObject *f1 = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "SourceFileLoader");
        if (f1) {
            printf("Found SourceFileLoader. \n");
            if (f1 && PyCallable_Check(f1)) {
                printf("SourceFileLoader  is callable. \n");

                PyObject *args = Py_BuildValue("ss", "mnist", ScriptPath.c_str());
                PyObject *SFL = PyObject_CallObject(f1, args);

                if (SFL) {
                    printf("SourceFileLoader called. \n");
                    PyObject *f2 = PyObject_GetAttrString(SFL, "load_module");
                    if (f2) {
                        printf("Load function found \n");
                        if (f2 && PyCallable_Check(f2)) {
                            printf("Load function callable. \n");
                            PyObject *mnist = PyObject_CallObject(f2, NULL);
                            if (mnist) {
                                printf("mnist module loaded. \n");
                            }
                            else {
                                printf("mnist module not loaded. \n");
                                PyErr_Print();
                            }
                            Py_XDECREF(mnist);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        printf("load function not found. \n");
                    }
                    Py_XDECREF(f2);
                }
                Py_XDECREF(args);
                Py_XDECREF(SFL);
            }
        }
        else {
            printf("Did not find SourceFileLoader. \n");
        }
        /*pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "main");
        if (pFunc && PyCallable_Check(pFunc)) {
            printf("Found function. \n");
        }*/
        Py_XDECREF(f1);
    }
    else {
        printf("Did not find module. \n");
    }


    Py_XDECREF(pName);
    Py_XDECREF(pModule);
    Py_XDECREF(pFunc);

    Py_Finalize();

    return 0;

}
```

The module mnist can't be loaded because of this import error:
[image]

I'm not sure if it is because I haven't included all the modules in my python path. Please advise.

Comment: Okay, so if anyone runs into this. Don't replace your PythonPath with your libs. I think the location of the modules are automagically figured out.

Comment: New problem is that I have to use WinPython's python interpreter located in the root directory for my code to run. How do I use that interpreter rather than the interpreter found one level deeper in the Python directory?